# Regex to split by square brackets and dots with python and re module

Tags: regex, python-2.7, split

I want to build a regex expression to split by `'.'` and `'[]'`, but here, I would want to keep the result between square brackets.

I mean:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("\.|[\[-\]]")
my_string = "a.b.c[0].d.e[12]"
pattern.split(my_string)

# >>> ['a', 'b', 'c', '0', '', 'd', 'e', '12', '']
```

But I would wish to get the following output (without any empty string):

```
# >>> ['a', 'b', 'c', '0', 'd', 'e', '12']
```

Would be it possible? I've tested with a lot of regex patterns and that is the best which I've found but it's not perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a quantifier in your regex and [filter](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter):

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'[.\[\]]+')
>>> my_string = "a.b.c[0].d.e[12]"
>>> filter(None, pattern.split(my_string))
['a', 'b', 'c', '0', 'd', 'e', '12']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! your regex expression is better than mine because it solves my problems with the empty strings between the result elements